# HackerRank Left Rotation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I looked up the solution to this problem yesterday and tried to solve on my own today but found myself trying to solve this problem in a different way.  I feel I may be overcomplicating the problem but I still want an answer to my possible solution just because it is bugging me to know (I am sure everyone has experienced this at some point or another).  Anyway here is the problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

My idea is that you would first check to see if your array length was equal to the rotations you want then you would simply return the original.  There is no work needed to be done.

My next idea would be to check to see if our rotations is greater than our array length.  If this is the case, we can either do rotations - array length or ABS VALUE(array length - rotations), which gives us the same result.  We can reassign this value to D.

Next, we can create a case to rotate right instead of left.  When your rotation is greater than your array length / 2, then we would not to rotate left since we are doing extra work.  We instead would want to rotate right.  For example:

Array Length 4
Rotations 3 (LEFT)

We can simply rotate right once instead of rotating left 3 times.  We could set the rotateRight boolean to true (otherwise set to false which indicated to rotateLeft as normal)

Anyway this is the part I get caught on.  I am unsure of how to rotate my elements here. I was thinking of returning a new array.  How can I get the correct values for my new array?  I am facing issues with IndexOutOfBounds exceptions. Can I also use try catches in this example or is it overkill?

Here is the code I have currently it should match my thoughts from up above:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
        int aLength = a.length;
        int counter = 0;
int[] newArray = new int[aLength];
        boolean rotateRight = false;
        if (aLength == d) {
            return a;
        }
        if (a.length - d < 0) {
            d = Math.abs(a.length - d);
        }

        if(d > a.length/2) {
            rotateRight = true;
        }
        
   
    return newArray;
    }
```

If you need any more info let me know.

Comment: if `a.length - d < 0`, then `d - a.length > 0`, why over-complexify using Math.abs?

Comment: You should provide the problem as text in the post, not  through a link only.

Comment: @Damien Hackerrank doesn't grab all the text needed.

Comment: @jhamon I don't believe it's over complexifying the problem.  It's pretty simple either grab the absolute value of the difference (if it's negative) or swap the numbers and get the difference as a positive number.  Either way you get the same result.

Comment: Your code returns an inexistant variable `newArray` and doesn't do anything on the `a` array. Regarding my first comment, you check on the very previous line that you know the result will be negative, why are you then unsure if it's positive or negative?

Comment: You don't need to calculate a new array. Directly write the result, reading the existing array in the good order

Comment: @Damien A new array seems to be a better idea in this case.  We can also set temp variables but a new array seems like the better idea.  We need to return the array here not just simply print it.

Comment: You've already got the idea that you don't have to rotate the array to the left, and you don't have to rotate the array the given number of times, as long as you end up with the same effect.  Now you need to understand that you don't have to "rotate" at all. Make a new array, and at each position in the new array, copy the element from the proper place in the old array.

Comment: @jhamon Yes I did not declare a newArray -- array of integers.  I need help with looping through the existing array and assigning the values into newArray, then finally returning the newArray as the result.  Back to your first comment:  we are doing a check to find the difference of the length of the original array and the rotations needed. I set this example to grab the absolute value if the rotations variable is greater than the array length.  I could have easily just have done d - array.length > 0 and stored the difference in D but I just did it my way.  Either way gives the same result.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'll try and use this.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: @trincot I'll update the post

Answer (score 2):

There is little benefit to trying to simplify the maths, if it leads to a harder-to-write program -- especially since you do not want to rotate the array at all, and can simply place the correct values in the correct places directly.

If the old position of element `i` was `i`, after `d` left-rotations of an array of size `len`, its new position will be `(i-d)%len`. If `d == len+1` this is indeed equivalent to `(i+1)%len` -- easier for humans, but computers calculate either expression just as happily.

So the suggested code is:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    for (int s=d, t=0; t<a.length; s++, t++) {
       // t is target position; s is source position
       b[t] = a[s%a.length];
    }
    return b;
}
```

*Note: code is untested*

Comment: OK a couple of things here:

1) In java arrays have a prop length.  They don't call the length method.  Anyways that's just a FYI.
2) What is n in this case? I am assuming your iterator in the for loop was meant to be:
s=(s+1)%d 

Is that correct?

Also I like this solution. It's different than the solution that I googled.  It's interesting to see others coding styles.

Comment: Fixed typos. The `% a.length` does the wrap-around when the array limits are reached - `a % d` would not have worked. Initially, `s = t+d`: that's the only place `d` is needed, to provide the initial offset between source and target positions.